# Real Analysis quals

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on this question: let $f_n$ Lebesgue measurable converge to $f$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ norm and also assume $\|f_n\|_2\le M$ for all $n$ (that is the $L^2$ norm of all $f_n$ is bounded by some constant $M$). Show that:

1) $f\in L^2$

2) Does it follow that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^2$

3) Show that $\|f-f_n\|_p\to 0$ for all $1<p<2$.

What I am doing is:

$|f|^2=|f-f_n+f_n|^2\le |f-f_n|^2 + 2|f_n||f-f_n| +|f_n|^2$

I know that if necessary I can pass to a subsequence of $f_n$ that converges pointwise a.e. to $f$; how can I reason for the first two terms? Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

For question 2 I think $f_n(x)=n\chi_{[0,1/n^2)}$ will give a counterexample.

I have no clue for 3. Any hints would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "quals" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie by "quals" I mean "qualifying exams"

Comment: Thanks, as I am not a native English speaker, I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @anonymous thank you, this certainly reduces the work, however I do not see how to reason about $\int |f-f_n|^2$. Any hint on this?

Comment: @Android 3) is a tricky application of Holder's inequality. Write $|g|^p = |g|^{2-p}|g|^{2p-2}$ and apply Holder with appropriate exponents $p'$ and $q'$ to show that $\int |g|^p dx \leq \left(\int |g|^2dx\right)^{p-1} \left(\int|g|dx\right)^{2-p}$ for $1<p<2$. Use $g=f-f_n$.

Comment: @AndroidNetizen Forgot to mention 1) is a direct application of Fatou's lemma.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jeff, it makes sense now!

Comment: Wait - sorry @Jeff, could you please elaborate a bit? How does it work? Many thanks.

Comment: @AndroidNetizen I filled in some details in my answer below. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

1) This is an application of Fatou's lemma. By passing to a subsequence $f_{n_k}$, we may assume $f_{n_k} \to f$ a.e. Now apply Fatou to the nonnegative sequence $f_{n_k}^2$. We have

$$\int f^2 dx \leq \liminf_{k\to \infty} \int f_{n_k}^2 \,dx \leq M^2.$$

2) Your counter example works here.

3) This is an application of Holder's inequality. Let $g=f-f_n$ and for $1<p<2$ write

$$|g|^p = |g|^{2p-2}|g|^{2-p}.$$

Apply Holder's inequality with exponents $p'=1/(p-1)$ and $q'=1/(2-p)$. (Check that $p',q'>1$ and $1/p' + 1/q'=1$). Then we have

$$\int |g|^p dx =\int |g|^{2p-2}|g|^{2-p} dx \leq \left(\int |g|^2 dx\right)^{p-1}\left(\int|g| dx\right)^{2-p}.$$

In other words

$$\|f-f_n\|_p^p \leq \|f-f_n\|_2^{2p-2}\|f-f_n\|_1^{2-p}\leq (2M)^{2p-2}\|f-f_n\|_1^{2-p}.$$

Since $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$, the estimate above gives convergence in $L^p$ for all $1<p<2$.